# Has ClassifyImagesOptions been deprecated?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-jdk, visual-recognition

If so, what was it replaced by? If not, I can't seem to import it properly. Could someone please give me pointers on how I could do that?

Comment: What you mean when you say you can't import it properly? What are you getting?

Comment: I'm using Java in Netbeans, it gives me a syntax error, "cannot find symbol". When I click on the little error notification on the left, where it would normally give me the option to auto-import the class, it only has the option to create a class of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about the Watson Developer Cloud [Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) (it would help to clarify this).

`ClassifyImagesOptions` class was not deprecated, still [part of the SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/visual_recognition/v3/model/ClassifyImagesOptions.java), and it has not been changed for some time already. You should check your classpath - without more details, it is hard to give more hints.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my tags. It's very strange because VisualRecognition, VisualClassifier, and VisualClassification all import properly and work just fine. Is ClassifyImageOptions not a part of the VisualRecognition API?